# installing npm modules removes react-native-cli

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react-native project where I install modules using

```
npm install some-module -save
```

package.json includes react-native-cli

Now, every time I do this the command react-native run-android is not available anymore. I have to run

```
yarn add react-native-cli
```

in order for it to be available again. Also, the gradle file of some modules get out of sync when I do this which means running Android Studio and updating these.

I find this very confusing. Earlier in the project, I was only using npm and had no problems.

Comment: Have you tried to install react-native-cli globally? `yarn global add react-native-cli`.

Comment: What is `-s` parameter for npm?

Comment: -s was a typo sorry

Comment: yarn global add ... does not make the cli available. I still don't understand why use two package managers

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try this

```
npm install -g <package> --save
```